# How to change login id without using another provider?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

I use an email address as my user name to get into Stack Exchange (along with various child sites). I do not use Facebook, Yahoo, Google, OpenID or any of the other myriad of logon providers, and I am not interested in signing up.

The email address I use has long since been deleted, and I'm cleaning up my web accounts. How do I change the user name to an email address that I currently use?

Comment: FIY, the regular SE email login *is* using OpenID, just SE's own OpenID. The dupe explains how to add another email address

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the email associated with a Stack Exchange OpenID credential (which is basically what our email/password combo is). I agree that it's a massive PITA/annoyance.

However, you can attach a new email/password credential to your account (instructions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114704/155160)). Once that's done, you can remove the credential linked to the now-deleted email address from your Q&A account and (optionally) [contact us](/contact) to delete the credential itself.